# Checking Login Credentials from SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create an app in Android Studio which requires a log in.  Just to test the app and see if it is reading the DB correctly I have the code in my main activity create a popup message if it can match the credentials:

```
        mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                DatabaseAccess databaseAccess=DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                databaseAccess.open();
                String user = mTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                String pwd = mTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                boolean res = db.checkUser(user, pwd);
                if (res)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                databaseAccess.close();
            }
        });
```

Following a tutorial, I created a check user method which does this:

```
    public boolean checkUser(String username, String password)
    {
        this.open();
        String[] columns = {"1"};
        String selection = "2"+" =?"+" and "+"6"+" =?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {username, password};
        c = db.query("MMI_USERINFO", columns, selection, selectionArgs,null, null, null);
        int count = c.getCount();
        this.close();
        c.close();

        if(count >0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Regardless of what I enter as the username/password, I always get the "Login Error" message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like below.

```
   public boolean checkUser(String username, String password)
    {
        this.open();
       
        final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from table_name;", null); // Replace with your desired SQL Query
       

       if (cursor != null) {
       try {
   
           count = cursor.getCount();
             
           } finally {
             cursor.close();
          }
        }
       if(count >0)
          return true;
       else
          return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this still does not work.  I am starting to wondering if my program is correctly reading the contents of the database.

Comment: You are most welcome. You can check the database connection is successfully connected or not.